# How to fix oci_execute(): ORA-00957: duplicate column name...?

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to insert form value data to Oracle database But I get this error ... please help ... ?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $nameen = $_POST['nameen'];
  $namear = $_POST['namear'];


echo $sql = "INSERT INTO TESTTABLE (ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD,NAMEEN,NAMEEN) VALUES (:id,:username,:password,:nameen,:namear)";
  $compiled = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':id', $id);
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':username', $username);
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':password', $password);
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':nameen', $nameen);
  oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':namear', $namear);

  oci_execute($compiled);

  if (! oci_execute($compiled)) {
    var_dump(oci_error()); 
} }
```

Comment: You wrote `(ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD,NAMEEN,NAMEEN)` instead of `(ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD,NAMEEN,NAMEAR)`. Twice name EN instead of once EN and once AR.

Comment: Really I'm dumb ... anyway, 's thank you so much...

Comment: Here's a little poem called "Debugging": When your code isn't working/there's problem galore/You fix one or two things/then get seven more/You're running on empty/and you're out of caffeine/you might just try reading/what's there on your screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have twice the same field, called « NAMEEN », in your INSERT statement :

```
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE
(ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD,NAMEEN,NAMEEN) VALUES ...
```

You want :

```
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE
(ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD,NAMEEN,NAMEAR) VALUES ...
```